# Is there a more succinct pattern for nested javascript event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I am playing around with dynamic HTML in javascript and would like to streamline and generalize the pattern, making it DRY and far more readable.

I have the following proof-of-concept js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var idElement = 'btnPrepend';
    var idRemove = 'liRemove';

    var html = `
            <ul>
                <li>${name}</li>
                <li><span id="${idRemove}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span><span><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></span>Go To Potions Class</li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Prepend" id="${idElement}" />
        `;
    // insert html into DOM 
    insertHTML('form', html);

    // add event listener(s) after insert 
    addEvent(idElement);
    addEvent2(idRemove);
  });

  const insertHTML = (tag = 'form', html, position = 'afterend', index = 0) => {
    document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[index].insertAdjacentHTML(position, html);
  }

  const addEvent = (id, event = 'click') => {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function() {

      var idLI = 'prependedDataLi';

      insertHTML('ul', `<li id="${idLI}">Prepending data</li>`, 'afterbegin');
      addNestedEvent(idLI);

      // insertHTML('ul', '<li>Prepending data</li>', 'afterbegin');
    });

    const addNestedEvent = (id, event = 'click') => {
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function(ev) {
        console.log('Prepended data was clicked! ');
        ev.stopPropagation();
      })
    }
  }

  const addEvent2 = (id, event = 'click') => {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function(ev) {

      $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
      ev.stopPropagation();
    });
  }



  // Click on bin icon to delete Todo
  $("ul").on("click", "span:nth-child(1)", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <div>
      <label for="txtName">Name</label>
      <input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

So far it works and achieves my aims, but those nested event handlers look messy to me and mixing native js and jQuery can't be good!?

Also if anyone knows the pure jQuery equivalent of this ??
document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[index].insertAdjacentHTML(position, html);

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Incidentally, $("ul").on("click", "span:nth-child(1)" won't work ! any ideas why ?

Comment: what do you mean by won't work?  The icon next to Go to potions fades out and removes the span as expected, leaving behind the other li.  If you want to remove the whole ul, you need to go up the parents and remove the ul

Comment: by "won't work" I mean the event handler isn't fired or reached. The reason the li is removed as expected is because the handler is written as const addEvent = (id, event = 'click') => {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function() { ....

I simply wanted to know why one syntax works but the jQuery .on version doesn't !

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted or recommended for codereview.stackexchange.com ?

It asks a question about front end design patterns essentially, one which I would have thought would garner intelligent discussion!

Comment: SO policy avoids "discussion" based questions and ones that are related to opinion, and that are not in the format of having a concrete answer.  codereview is where you would go for "how can I make this code better?".  I don't know about the downvote.

Comment: See: [What distinguishes Code Review from Stack Overflow?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/225005), [Don't ask these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).  It is also not in the format of framework/library specific questions where there is a very concrete guideline for design patterns, such as something that React might have.  There will almost never be a case where a jQuery pattern recommendation isn't subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` tag is not created yet when you attach the listener.  You also destroy the `ul` on every submit click, so the event listener attached to the `ul` is invalidated every time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var idElement = 'btnPrepend';
    var idRemove = 'liRemove';

    var html = `
            <ul>
                <li>${name}</li>
                <li><span id="${idRemove}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span><span><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></span>Go To Potions Class</li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Prepend" id="${idElement}" />
        `;
    // insert html into DOM 
    insertHTML('form', html);

    // add event listener(s) after insert 
    addEvent(idElement);
    addEvent2(idRemove);
  });

  const insertHTML = (tag = 'form', html, position = 'afterend', index = 0) => {
    document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[index].insertAdjacentHTML(position, html);
  }

  const addEvent = (id, event = 'click') => {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function() {

      var idLI = 'prependedDataLi';

      insertHTML('ul', `<li id="${idLI}">Prepending data</li>`, 'afterbegin');
      addNestedEvent(idLI);

      // insertHTML('ul', '<li>Prepending data</li>', 'afterbegin');
    });

    const addNestedEvent = (id, event = 'click') => {
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function(ev) {
        console.log('Prepended data was clicked! ');
        ev.stopPropagation();
      })
    }
  }


function addEvent2(){

  // Click on bin icon to delete Todo
  $("ul").on("click", "span:nth-child(1)", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-+Q/z/qVOexByW1Wpv81lTLvntnZQVYppIL1lBdhtIq0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <div>
      <label for="txtName">Name</label>
      <input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```